# v-treeview @input calling method twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

I have added a treeview in my vue component and on the selecting node it should update an array and then show the checkbox as selected. Currently, I am stuck in a situation where I am selecting elements from the tree (which is a folder containing an item) and then going to another folder to select different items. When I am opening the folder I previously selected, it will remove all the selected elements.

Here is my code:

```
<v-treeview
  :items="patchItemsTreeList"
  v-model="selectedPatchItemUUIDs"
  @input="onChangeOfPatchSelection"
  :name="'patchItemsTree'"
  :open="openParentNode"
  :item-text="'text'"
  :key="fold"
  :open-all="openParentNode.length === 0"
  :selection-type="selectionType"
  selectable
  open-on-click
  dense

@input=onChangeOfPatchSelection
```

This method is called twice interrupting my logic and deleting my selected items from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching from `@input` to either [`@update:active`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#events-update:active) or [`@update:open`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#events-update:open). In your case I believe that you need `@update:active`

```html
<v-treeview
  :items="patchItemsTreeList"
  v-model="selectedPatchItemUUIDs"
  @update:active="onChangeOfPatchSelection"
  :name="'patchItemsTree'"
  :open="openParentNode"
  :item-text="'text'"
  :key="fold"
  :open-all="openParentNode.length === 0"
  :selection-type="selectionType"
  selectable
  open-on-click
  dense
/>
```

What this will do is instead of emitting the array of selected items, it will emit the open items instead.